# How to protect a sheet via Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I see we have AddProtectedRangeRequest, but I want to protect the whole sheet just like you can do through the UI.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs for [ProtectedRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#protectedrange).range: *The range that is being protected. The range may be fully unbounded, in which case this is considered a protected sheet.*

So if you only set the range's sheetId and leave the start/end row/col empty (e.g unbounded), it will protect the whole sheet.

Comment: Man, that thought actually crossed my mind, and I thought I checked the doc for it... guess I somehow missed it anyway. Thank you!